# How to load custom settings from appsettings.js

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, appsettings

I've added some custom settings to my first ASP.NET (Core 2.1) application but I don't know how to access it from C#. I guess I'm not initializing it properly, could somebody take a look please?

appsettings.js:

```
"DatabaseSettings": 
{
    "Hostname": "localhost",
    "Port": "12345",
    "DbName": "myDatabase"
}
```

And here's the class for it:

```
public class DatabaseSettings
{
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string DbName { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings"));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMvc();
        var databaseSettings = Configuration.Get<DatabaseSettings>();
        Mongo.Initialize("mongodb://" + databaseSettings.Hostname + ":" + databaseSettings.Port, databaseSettings.DbName);
    }
}
```

The properties return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you added the setting using `services.Configure<T>()`, it's able to be injected into other classes using `IOptions<T>`.  You can also reference it by specifying `IOptions<T>` in the `Configure()` method of your startup class. In your case:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IOptions<DatabaseSettings> settings)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseMvc();
    var databaseSettings = settings.Value;
    Mongo.Initialize("mongodb://" + databaseSettings.Hostname + ":" + databaseSettings.Port, databaseSettings.DbName);
}
```

Comment: `IOptions<T>` is completely unnecessary. The whole point of using `services.Configure<T>` is to allow you to inject the configuration class directly. If anything, use `IOptionsSnapshot<T>` as that at least gives you config reload support, though for this particular use case, it wouldn't make a difference since this is all occurring during startup.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, yes, for normal dependency injection, you could/should then just inject the class directly into a constructor!  But if you try to use just the class (without `IOptions`) into `Configure()` method in the startup, it will throw an exception saying it could not resolve a service of type `T`.

Answer (score 4):

Just make your Configuration variable global. and you can put it anywhere is startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
    services.AddMvc();
    services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings"));
   }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseMvc();
    var settingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings");
    var settings = settingsSection.Get<DatabaseSettings>();
    Mongo.Initialize("mongodb://" + settings.Hostname + ":" + settings.Port, settings.DbName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Best answer, and the way it's handled by default in ASP.NET Core application project template. However, it's not accurate to call this "global". It's still a local, just scoped to the class instance.

Comment: It is global Chris, also if you want to use some of this values in any of your pages of your .net core project you just need to do this... @Configuration["Message"] try it... it really works! but you need to inject the IConfiguration using @inject IConfiguration Configuration

Comment: Umm.. no, it's not global. It exists in your view *because* you're injecting it. The same as if you injected it into a class constructor. It's not using the property on `Startup`.

Answer (score 2):

adding to [Nicholas Reynolds answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50841902/1752345) 
you can use

```
var sett = new DatabaseSettings();
Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings").Bind(sett);
```

or if you want to get single value you can use

```
var hostname = Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings:Hostname");
```